# jquery fadeIn/fadeOut not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs that I want to have fade in and out depending on a nav panel. I am running into an issue with two of the divs, but the others work fine so I am not sure what is happening.

here is the jQuery code, here the two divs that are wacky have been singled out, the real code generalizes it to work for all divs:

```
    $('#behind_the_lens').click(function() {
                          $('#gallaries-page').fadeOut(0);
                          $('#behind_the_lens-page').fadeIn(750);
                          $('#pricing-page').fadeOut(750);
                         });
    $('#pricing').click(function() {
                          $('#pricing-page').fadeIn(750);
                          $('#behind_the_lens-page').fadeOut(750);
                         });
```

When the first function runs `#pricing-page` just hides, no fading and `#behind_the_lens-page` does fade.

When the second function runs `#pricing-page` waits for `#behind_the_lens-page` to fade out, then it instantly shows.

this does not happen for any other combination of divs so it is very strange to me.

as for the contents of these divs, one `#pricing-page` uses a table and the other uses a floating layout. but there layouts types are not unique from other divs.

In summary, why is it working this way for these divs but not the others? furthermore, why is it doing this at all?

Edit: was able to come up with a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u3u8jsqr/1/) that shows the problem.

Comment: what's your markup for these divs like? are any of them descendants/ancestors of the others?

Comment: please, provide fiddle with the whole code including the part that is working and the defected part to help us experience the problem better

Comment: all of the divs that I have fading in and out have absolute positions and they are children of the body

Comment: @Gouda it would be too difficult to put all the necessary things on fiddle, each div is quite large, sorry

Comment: when in isolation it works fine so the code provided is not enough http://jsfiddle.net/ekk8axed/

Comment: @Luca each page has several images, local to my computer, and I have a separate css file for each div, if you have any suggestions on the best way to put it on fiddle I will do my best, but as of now it just seems too difficult. also the divs all overlap one another, maybe that will help.

Comment: @Luca I was able to simplify the code and show the problem, see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fading in and fading out simultaneously. Watch the scrollbar, your "clicked" page is appearing as the currently visible is disappearing, and jumps up into position after the visible completely disappears (display:none).

Use the complete callback on fadeOut so that fading in happens after fading out finishes.

https://jsfiddle.net/u3u8jsqr/2/

JS

```
if (thisID != visibleID) {
    $(visibleID).fadeOut(750, function () {
        $(thisID).fadeIn(750);
    });                                
}
```

Comment: I want them to fade in and out at the same time. I thought `position: absolute` would allow them to overlap each other, and it does but apparently `#pricing-page` did not have that attribute. I will accept your answer because it led me to the solution. Thanks